# How to hide a label for Autocomplete on onFocus in Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to Material-ui. I am trying to customise `Autocomplete` component from `@material-ui/labs`. I wanted to hide a label of field. Can somebody help me customise the same?
I tried adding `hiddenLabel="true"` flag to Autocomplete element, but it's not working. Below is a sandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jwmp2

Comment: Check the [document](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) to find what you can use as a props for `Autocomplete`

Comment: you can give a try:  InputLabelProps={{shrink: false}}

Comment: You should go with placeholder instead of label. i.e. `placeholder="Combo box"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to hide the label on onSelect than you can use placeholder instead label in TextField or remove the label for blank value.

Here is the code sandbox link for the same 
  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6kphs

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just remove the label for the text field, then just remove label part in `<TextField {...params} variant="outlined" />`

Here is the codesandbox for the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rzxsi

Answer (score 1):

## remove label ="some value"

```
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Enter Name" />}
```

to

```
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
```